# RegEx and stringr package

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am an R newbie and have troubles with my programming homework.

The input is a poem:

```
poem <- c(
  "Am Tag, an dem das L verschwand,", 
  "da war die Luft voll Klagen.",
  "Den Dichtern, ach, verschlug es glatt",
  "ihr Singen und ihr Sagen.",
  "Nun gut. Sie haben sich gefasst.",
  "Man sieht sie wieder schreiben.",
  "Jedoch:",
  "Solang das L nicht wiederkehrt,",
  "muß alles Flickwerk beiben.")
```

Now I need to extract all the capital letters and combine them into one word. 
I am doing this with the following code:

```
poem_cap <- str_extract_all(poem, "[[:upper:]]")
```

Then I unlist `poem_cap`:

```
one_word <- unlist(poem_cap)
one_word
```

The next logical step is to apply `str_c`:

```
one_word2 <- str_c(one_word, sep="")
```

But R keeps putting out separate letters! 
If I copy the output of `one_word2`, separate it with commas and apply `str_c` to the output, it works:

```
one_word2 <- str_c("A", "T", "L", "L", "K", "D", "D", "S", "S", "N", "S", "M", "J", "S", "L", "F", sep="")
one_word
```

Why does this happen? Is there a mistake I'm making? How do I transform `one_word2` into something `str_c` I can work with?

Comment: Use `collapse = ""` instead of `sep = ""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base `R` approach, you can simply use `gsub` in a one liner to keep only capital letters and paste them (with collapse, as @David Arenburg underlined):

```
paste(gsub('[^A-Z]','',poem), collapse='')
#[1] "ATLLKDDSSNSMJSLF"
```

Comment: Nice and efficient base approach (+1).